# Rigid type error combined with IO and polymorphic types

Tags: haskell

I am writing an interpreter for a simple language as a project at university, and there is an option to write in some debugging functionality. I thought this would be simple but after taking a break of about a week due to frustration I have come back to deal with this.

The entire haskell file is about 250 lines so I don't want to post the whole thing, but if I haven't given enough information please let me know.

I have this function

```
interpret_statement :: Prog -> (Var -> Val -> Vars -> o) -> Vars -> Stmt -> o
```

where (Var -> Val -> Vars -> o) is a debugging function - one of 2 possibilities that I choose

```
pure_passthrough :: Var -> Val -> Vars -> Vars -- does no IO
write_debugging_info :: Var -> Val -> Vars -> IO Vars -- does IO
```

I also have another function

```
interpret_function :: Prog -> (Var -> Val -> Vars -> o) -> Vars -> [Stmt] -> Val
```

which contains a line

```
interpret_function prog debug_function vars (x:xs) = interpret_function prog debug_function (interpret_statement prog debug_function vars x) xs
```

and is one of 3 lines that gives me a rigid type error saying that

```
Expected type: Var -> Val -> Vars -> Vars
Actual type: Var -> Val -> Vars -> o
```

Everything was working completely fine before trying to introduce IO. I have done it this way due to the answer of a separate question on this site that suggested I use a polymorphic function to tell the program whether to do IO or not at run-time depending on whether I receive a command line argument or not.

But now it causes problems because I have a couple of co-dependent functions that I now need to pass polymorphic variables to and from? Oh the humanity! I really think I'm getting better at Haskell guys but this one has me COMPLETELY stumped. How is the "Actualy type" Var -> Val -> Vars -> o which is polymorphic and not really specific?

Note: If I need to include more information PLEASE let me know - I have started with as little as possible so I don't overload people with unnecessary information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call `(interpret_statement prog debug_function vars x)` is in a position where it must return `Vars`, it cannot return the type `o`.

In `interpret_function`, the return type does not depend on `o`, so even if you pass in a debug function that returns an IO monad, the result of `interpret_function` is not an IO monad.

My Haskell is a bit rusty, but I believe you could change `interpret_function` so that its type becomes

```
interpret_function :: (Monad m) => Prog -> (Var -> Val -> Vars -> m Vars) -> Vars -> [Stmt] -> m Val
```

where `m` will be either `IO` or some trivial monad ([perhaps this one](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/1.1.0.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Identity.html)).

Now the implementation of that particular case would go something like this:

```
interpret_function prog debug_function vars (x:xs) =
  do vars' <- interpret_statement prog debug_function vars x
     return $ interpret_function prog debug_function vars' xs
```

Comment: Ahhh I see it now. interpret_function requires a Vars type to be in that location. I *could* include the monad, but is there some other way to do this? It seems as though I am having to change the typing and/or pattern matching of every single line in my program as a result of including this IO. Of course... beggars can't be choosers, but I can remain hopeful...

Comment: @nebffa In this case, it's relatively easy to see that you can't avoid adding the monad: Your function `interpret_function` is supposed to potentially perform IO, but it does return `Val`, which is a non-IO type, so it cannot perform any IO with this result type.

Comment: Monadic I/O indeed tends to be "contagious".

Comment: @mpartel oh god it's spreading!!!! Ok thankyou both for the reassurance that this is the way it needs to be. I am going to sleep now and will wake up tomorrow to deal with this a bit more

Comment: @kosmikus You said that interpret_function will do IO - in Haskell do we say that a function performs IO even if it doesn't do the IO itself, but rather it calls another function that may do the IO? Because in this case it's not interpret_function doing it, right?

Comment: @mpartel Now that I am spreading o throughout my program in place of Vars, I encounter a problem which I expected to. I have pattern matched Vars thusly: "interpret_statement prog debug_function vars@(Vars _ b c d) (Assign A expr)", what is the correct syntax for matching against something that COULD BE Vars but also COULD BE IO Vars?

Comment: @mpartel actually upon some thinking, I will likely need to do "case ... of" pattern matching right? i.e. case vars of 1. Vars a b c d -> .... 2. IO Vars a b c d ->

Comment: I recommend abstracting over the monad `m` (instead of an opaque `o`), and using the `do` syntax as shown in the answer.

Comment: @nebffa If, in order to determine the final result of type `Vars`, IO might have to be performed, then yes, the result has to be of type `IO Vars`. Regarding structuring your code: parameterizing by `o` will most likely not be enough, because you have to be explicit about how the order in which potential `IO` effects occur. So as mpartel says, you should try abstracting over the monad (which can then be instantiated to either `IO` or `Identity`).

Comment: Ok thanks guys. Using o was an answer to a previous question I had on here about a week ago. No wonder it doesn't work. It's about this time I wish I could just do *import Python* and then *print myVariable*. I will work on "abstracting over the monad m" but I know I am bound to have questions along the way (I have never done any of this before)

Comment: I probably shouldn't be telling you this, but for quick and dirty temporary debugging print statements, it's possible to use [System.IO.Unsafe](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/System-IO-Unsafe.html), which allows you to "escape" the IO monad. I certainly wouldn't leave it in the final product though. It's generally considered **very** bad practice. Also, it's cheating :)

Comment: @mpartel HAHA ok .. I know I will want to cheat :- ), but I will do things right so I learn. HOWEVER, so I know how to use this (oh my god it would be a godsend to be able to print stuff whenever) - how would I use it in this situation?

Comment: [Debug.Trace](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Debug-Trace.html) wraps that, though it may be instructive to implement `trace` yourself too.

Comment: @mpartel ... ummm.... what is to stop me from using Debug.Trace to do my debug in the first place? It seems to work just fine

Comment: The question was phrased in a way that led me to believe you aimed to write an interpreter with debugging functionality as a feature, as opposed to needing to simply quickly debug your code. For the latter, Debug.Trace is fine, but for the former it's very questionable IMHO.

Comment: @mpartel Ok I have not gone ahead with Debug.Trace and instead have monadified the code. Woohoo!!! I finally got that to work... my god. So now the program is monadified but does no IO. The type of pretty much every function I have is (Monad m) => ... ... -> m Vars (or maybe m Val) etc. When I try to do IO now, it gives me errors like "could not deduce (m ~ IO)". How do I do my IO at this point??? It's happening mpartel!!! I can feel it!!

Comment: If googling for that error doesn't help, try opening a new question and show in more detail where the error occurs.

Comment: @mpartel Nevermind - I have finally been able to solve it... I didn't need (Monad m) => ... m Vars. What worked was changing all type signatures to something like interpret_function :: Prog -> MaybeDebug -> Vars -> Stmt -> IO Vars. With everything returning IO, plus proper use of do and return I got it working... thank god. This has been the most annoying thing I think I have ever done in programming. Thankyou for your patience, I really can't thank you enough